# What type of bonsai tree do I have

Tags: bonsai

[image][image]

I have just received this Bonsai tree and was wondering what species it was, Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4):

I think it's Zelkova or Japanese Elm, though they are very similar to Chinese Elm. Care requirements are more or less the same though; technically, its an outdoor bonsai, but it will need protection in cold winters so it doesn't freeze. However, if you've only recently received this tree and you're in the northern hemisphere, then its probably best to keep it indoors somewhere cool, away from heat sources, with good daylight, until next year, because it will have been reared indoors all this time. You can place outside next year in late spring/early summer, hardening it off first, in a position out of direct sunlight. More care information here: [Japanese Elm (Zelkova)](https://www.bonsaiempire.com/tree-species/zelkova).